# Each nested attributes in a table in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I've got a form with nested attributes, now I'm wanting to show on a table, but I'm not able to break the line it gets interacting as a column. How can I do? What can I do?

[Here's an image of my current table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBBTH.png)

```
<% @salmonella.process_salmonellas.each do |process| %>
<tr align="center">
    <td><%= process.title %></td>
    <table>
        <% process.stages.each do |stage| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= stage.title %></td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <% stage.lines.each do |line| %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= line.material %></td>
                                <td><%= line.indicator_name %></td>
                            </tr>
                        <% end %>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</tr>
```

[And this is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwMFa.png)

That would be more or less the table template I drew in my head:

```
 <table>
    <!-- Each for principal object -->
    <tr>
        <td><!-- fields of principal object --></td>
        <td>
            <!-- each nested attributes from principal object and the model -->
            <tr>
                <td><!-- fields of second object--></td>
                <td>
                    <!-- each from model and another model that is nested too from principal object and model -->
                    <tr>
                        <td><!-- fields of third object --></td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

that's how nested this is in my controller:

```
def salmonella_params
  params.require(:salmonella).permit(:title,
    process_salmonellas_attributes: [
      :id,
      :title,
      :_destroy,
      stages_attributes: [
        :id,
        :title,
        :_destroy,
        lines_attributes:[
          :id,
          :material,
          :indicator_name,
          :_destroy
        ]
      ]
    ])
end
```

Comment: You mean you don't have rows? Cause thats because you only use `<td>` and no `<tr>` (which stands for table row). If this is the case please have a quick read at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: I tried putting the `<tr>` but it does not recognize it as `<td>`

Comment: Thats because you have to put the `<td>`  inside the `<tr>` (and that inside the `<table>`  ), watch one of the examples in the link I send.

Comment: 3 tables? I'll update the question

Comment: with 3 tables mess everything

Comment: 1 table, then 1 `<tr>` for each row  you want. and inside the `<tr>` you put multiple `<td>` (The amount of horizontal columns you want). Did you watch the link I send you??

Comment: yes, I saw. But there are only normal tables, this I know to do `<table>` , `<tr>`,  `<td>`  this for a class works well, for two until it goes, but with 3 being that each are one inside the other breaks the whole table. Why one `<tr>` may have several `<tr>` in it.

Comment: I understood what you meant right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Jeremy recommended and it looked like this:

```
<% @salmonella.process_salmonellas.each do |process| %>
    <tr>
        <% process.stages.each do |cont| $b = cont.lines.count  end %>
        <td rowspan="<%= $b %>"><%= process.title %></td>
        <% process.stages.each do |stage| %>
        <td rowspan="<%= stage.lines.count %>"><%= stage.title %></td>
            <% stage.lines.each_with_index do |line, o| %>
                <% if o == 0 %>
                    <td><%= line.material %></td>
                    <td><%= line.indicator_name %></td>
                <% else %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= line.material %></td>
                        <td><%= line.indicator_name %></td>
                    </tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now it's working the way the image works.